# How to make a shell script run automatically daily?

Tags: linux, perl, windows-xp

My operating system is windows xp and my server is Linux. I have developed a code in perl(saved in shell file).

I want to connect to Linux machine from Windows using your script only and then run a script on linux and this should be done on daily basis and automatically also.
Is it possible to do that?

Comment: on which machine do you want to run the scheduled task? on linux you would use cron.

Answer (score 2):

Shell file under windows? that's called a batch file

Here is an example how you can set up a [scheduled task on windows](http://drupal.org/node/31506)

If your remote machine is on linux, you can read [here](http://www.scrounge.org/linux/cron.html) how you can set them.

You have several options to run the script on remote machine:

- copy the file on the remote machine in the same location with the same file name (with ftp or ssh you can do this with another script) and set the linux machine's cron job to execute that same file daily
- install a (web) server on the linux machine and create a web page through which's interface to upload and execute the script (this way you don't have to set up a cron job on linux)
- create a script on the linux machine which to connect to another service (like a ftp location), download the needed script (the one which you want to execute) and execute it. Put the downloading script in your cron to execute whenever you want
- use [Net::SSH::Perl](http://www.stupidfool.org/perl/docs/perldoc/Net/SSH/Perl.html) in your script to run commands on the linux machine (for this, you need ssh access to that machine, obviuosly)

Comment: I need to run this script from my windows machine on to the remote machine which has Linux as its OS. so I need to connect to that machine in the script first right?

Comment: another way would be to use an ssh (or telnet) client like [putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) to execute the script from the windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Create a Scheduled Task which runs the PERL.exe  with the script file name as an argument.

Comment: Dont I need to connect to my server first to that? I need to run this code in remote server which is of Linux.

Comment: I was assuming you could already run your script against the server and were just looking for a way to schedule it.  What exactly are you having trouble doing?

Comment: These are my requirements: I need to connect to linux machine in the code itself, and it should run daily automatically.

Comment: Is your server running Samba?  If so you can probably just connect using a UNC path.  Posting your script code may help us to help you.